# Understanding chiral algebra and $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R$ symmetry of Lagrangian for massless quarks

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, quarks

I am new to the idea of chiral algebra, so I only have one specific Lagrangian to refer to for my question.

Let's consider $\psi(x) = \begin{pmatrix} u(x) \\ d(x) \end{pmatrix}$, a quark field where $u(x)$ and $d(x)$ are 4 components spinor each.

Assuming the quarks are massless, the associated Lagrangian is:

$\mathcal{L_{massless}}  = i\bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu\psi = i\bar\psi_L\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu\psi_L + i\bar\psi_R\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu\psi_R$

Then if we consider the following transformations:

$\psi_L \to e^{i\frac{\vec{\alpha_L}}{2} \cdot \vec{\sigma}} \psi_L$

and

$\psi_R \to e^{i\frac{\vec{\alpha_R}}{2} \cdot \vec{\sigma}} \psi_R$

We see that the $\mathcal{L_{massless}}$ is invariant under those two transformations.

Then we go on to show the existence of conserved currents and charges given by (omitting derivations):

Iso-currents: $j_L^{i\mu} = \bar\psi_L\gamma^\mu \frac{\sigma^i}{2} \psi_L$ and $j_R^{i\mu} = \bar\psi_R\gamma^\mu \frac{\sigma^i}{2} \psi_R$

Iso-charges: $Q_L^i(t) = \int d^3x j_L^{i0} (\vec{x},t)$  and $Q_R^i(t) = \int d^3x j_R^{i0} (\vec{x},t)$

From here, we can also define axial vector current $j_5^{i\mu} = j_R^{i\mu} -j_L^{i\mu} = \bar\psi\gamma^\mu\gamma_5\frac{\sigma^i}{2}\psi $ and prove that its divergence is 0.

Then comes the idea that the charges $Q_L^i$ and $Q_R^i$ form a chiral algebra of $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R$ and basically in our lecture, we explicitly proved the following:

$[Q_L^i,Q_L^j] = i \epsilon_{ijk}Q_L^k$

$[Q_R^i,Q_R^j] = i \epsilon_{ijk}Q_R^k$

$[Q_L^i,Q_R^j] = 0$

Okay, so far so good. Now, let's bring back the mass terms in the Lagrangian by getting rid of the assumptions that the quarks are massless. Then we have:

$\mathcal{L_{mass}} = i\bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu\psi = i\bar\psi_L\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu\psi_L + i\bar\psi_R\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu\psi_R - \bar\psi_Lm\psi_R - \bar\psi_Rm\psi_L$

where $ m = diag (m_u, m_d)$

Now, even though the massless terms (the first and the second terms) are still invariant under $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R$ transformation, the last two mixed terms are not.

My question is the following:

How does the introduction of the mass term in the lagrangian affect the $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R$ chiral algebra?

The reason I am confused is some books and lecture notes go on to explain ( by explicit derivation) that for massive lagrangian it is now the case that $\partial_{\mu}j_5^{i\mu} \ne 0$  or in other words, the axial vector current is no longer conserved. However, since $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R$ is no longer a symmetry of the massive lagrangian, why do we need to worry about whether the axial vector current is conserved or not?